# subset a pandas dataframe with ifelse statement

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-s3

I am going through some csvs in an S3 bucket and I'm trying to see if there's any June data in the bucket that should only contain July data.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import os
import boto3
import s3fs
from io import StringIO
import numpy as np

fs = myawskeys
bucket = myawsbucket
files = mylistoffiles

master = []
for file in files:
    with fs.open(file) as f:
        df = pd.read_csv(f, delimiter='|')
        df['occurred_at'] = pd.to_datetime(df['occurred_at'])
        df['generated_at'] = pd.to_datetime(df['generated_at'])
        for row in df['occurred_at'].dt.month:
            if row == 6:
                master.append(df.loc[row])
```

I want to create a new dataframe (list = master in my example) of rows that are in month 6 . How do I subset df when my condition is matched?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost correct, instead of for loop, you do:

```
master = df[df['occurred_at'].dt.month == 6]
```

Not to forget, we are creating `master` as a dataframe now instead of a `list`. So, later to append to `master` dataframe you can do:

```
master = pd.concat([master, df])
```